# Does anyone know a word that means 'small item of high importance'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm starting a novelty website and am currently trying to name it. We want the same feeling you get when you see a nice old store that has thousands of small gits n' gadgets that make you want to find a trinket to take home. Basically, the feeling i got from the movie "Mr.Magorium's Wonder Emporium" if anyone has seen it.

Me and my friend want a two word title, and currently have this:
________ Emporium

So you can see we're having some trouble. The closest word i've found is 'Memento', but we are trying to find one that better phonetically rolls of the tongue. Any suggestions will be helpful!

Comment: *heirlooms* are handed down from generation to generation.  The Items in your store are certain to become heirlooms.  On the other hand, you ask about Items of value in the title but then talk about gits, gadgets and trinkets which are not valuable or important at all.

Comment: Probably not what you're looking for, but how about "MacGuffin"? http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MacGuffin

Comment: As it is Scots not English I shan't post this as an answer but you could do worse than open a 'Whigmaleerie Emporium'! http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/whigmaleerie 'A decorative or fanciful object, a piece of ornamentation, in dress, stonework, etc., used gen. with depreciatory force, a knick-knack, gew-gaw, bauble, a fantastic contrivance or contraption'.

Comment: there is the term "curio" ~A rare, unusual, or intriguing object.~ https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/curio   .. not really suggesting 'high importance' at all though

Answer (score 2):

**keepsake**

> Noun: keepsake  'keep,seyk
>
> Something of sentimental value
>
> - souvenir, token, relic

-- [WordWeb](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=keepsake)